# How to check hasMany relation record is empty in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get those record who has not join with has many table
my query like this

```
$result = Recipes::select('id')->where("name", 'like', '%' . $item . '%')
                    ->with(['categoryItem'])
                    ->get();
```

And my output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [foodable_id] => 1
                            [foodable_type] => Recipes
                            [created_at] => 2017-04-14 16:18:22   
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [category_item] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get just those record who has empty category_item detail. in bellow example i want to get  index 1 record so how can i give condition with query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and you want to get recipies which don't have `categoryItem`, you want to use [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
Recipes::where('name', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
       ->doesntHave('categoryItem')
       ->get();
```

I assume that `categoryItem` is defined relation since you're trying to use it in `with()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Maybe this can help .
Dont forget to add on top of your file :

```
use DB;
```

And your result will be something like this

`$result = Recipes::select('id')->where("name", 'like', '%' . $item . '%')
                     ->whereHas('categoryItem', function($q) {
                        $q->where(DB::raw('count(*)),'>', 0); 
                     })->get();`

I did't tested the count function hope this works, Good luck with it